# Grails - BootStrap.groovy - null pointer issues

Tags: grails, groovy, bootstrapping, grails-2.1

Having issues with BootStrap.groovy loading development data. Prior it had always loaded data, but now has stopped throwing the below error when running grails run-app.

```
Message: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
- Field error in object 'spotlight.content.Profile' on field 'portfolio': rejected value  [null];
```

My 2 models are as follows;

```
class Portfolio {
   Profile profile

String portfolioName
String portdescrip
Integer portpublished
Date dateCreated
Date lastUpdated
```

AND

```
class Profile {
   static belongsTo = [portfolio: Portfolio]

String portfoliohtml
String portfolioEmail
String portfoliocc
String portfolioAdmin
String portfolioFilestore
String portfolioColor
String bugzillaproduct
String bugzillacomponent
String rtqueue
String teamqueueemail
String etherpadurl
Integer siteupload
Date dateCreated
Date lastUpdated
```

Within the BootStrap.groovy file I have the following;

```
import java.util.Date;
import spotlight.content.Profile
import spotlight.content.Portfolio

class BootStrap { 

def init = { servletContext ->

    def profile = new Profile(portfoliohtml:"No",
            portfolioEmail: "ian@ian.com",
            portfolioAdmin:"Ian Neilsen",
            bugzillaproduct:"bz prod name",
            bugzillacomponent:"comp name",
            siteupload:1,
            portfoliocc: "ian@ian.com",
            portfolioColor:"red",
            portfolioFilestore:"blah",
            rtqueue:"queue name",
            teamqueueemail:"ian@ian.com",
            etherpadurl:"http://url.com",
            ).save(failOnError: true)

    def portfolio = new Portfolio(portfolioName:"Portfolio 1",
                            portdescrip:"portfolio descrition field",
                            portpublished:1,
                            portfolio:profile).save(failOnError: true)

}
```

I have tried every incarnation of adding my profile object to the portfolio object without any luck. As I said previously this worked and has now stopped throwing the null error.

has got me stumped any ideas?

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have several mistakes. 
One (but not causing the error message) is, that you try to add your `profile` instance to `portfolio` property of your `portfolia` instance. `Portfolio` has no property `portfolio`.

Regarding your errormessage, try following:

```
def portfolio = new Portfolio(portfolioName:"Portfolio 1", ...)
portfolio.profile = new Profile(...)
portfolio.save(failOnError: true)
```

For further reading, look at the [Many-to-one and one-to-one (GORM)](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#manyToOneAndOneToOne) section of the grails docs.

Comment: oh man thanks very much. Late in the afternoon and you just stopped me banging my head on table. Still has me stumped why this worked prior. I had changed the model profile from siteprofile througout the app and since then it has decided to drop of the face of the earth. Still learning grails. thanks mate